# Помогите разобраться с пакетом Tor в Debian 9.8.0

Tags: debian, tor

Я установил пакет Tor и сделал так, как написано на оф сайте: установил apt-transport-https, добавил ключ-подписи, и выполнил все следующие команды:

```
# apt install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
# apt build-dep tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
$ mkdir ~/debian-packages; cd ~/debian-packages
$ apt source tor
$ cd tor-*
$ debuild -rfakeroot -uc -us
$ cd ..
```

В общем всё как написано в инструкции. И ничего не получилось. Может я в source.list что то не то добавил. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Последняя команда debuild не выполняется? Какие ошибки в консоль валятся? Была ошибка `E: Невозможно найти пакет с исходным кодом для tor`?

Comment: debuild выполнилась. Когда я пишу tor -f /etc/tor/torrc то он выдаёт ошибку: Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports

Comment: `Failed to bind one of the listener ports` значит, что порт занят. Что в файле `/etc/tor/torrc` - есть он? Какой порт в нем указан?

Answer (score 0):

на **официальном** сайте дистрибутива *debian gnu/linux* написано, что [пакет `tor` имеется в репозиториях для всех актуальных версий](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tor&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) этого дистрибутива.

и пакет можно просто установить:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tor
```

и программа *tor* после этого будет сразу же запущена в режиме демона (с параметрами по умолчанию). в чём легко убедиться, например, с помощью программы `pgrep`(приведён пример вывода):

```
$ pgrep -a tor
11672 /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0
```

ну а дальше всё как и с самым обычным демоном — с помощью программы `systemctl` его можно остановить, запустить, перезапустить, отключить, включить (`stop`, `start`, `restart`, `disable`, `enable`):

```
$ sudo systemctl команда tor.service
```

параметры (по умолчанию) берутся из файла `/etc/tor/torrc`. надо изменить параметры — правьте этот файл и не забывайте после правки перезапускать демона.